# What does this SQL statement "WHERE table_a.key (+)= table_b.key" means?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am reading through some lecture notes of my school, and I come across this slide:

**Chapter:** Data Integration and ETL Process

**Slide Title:** Duplicate Values Problem

**Text:** Duplicate values invariably exist. Eliminating can be time consuming, although it is a simple task to perform.

**SQL Example:**

```
SELECT ...
FROM table_a, table_b
WHERE table_a.key (+)= table_b.key
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM table_a, table_b
WHERE table_a.key = table_b.key (+);
```

Specifically, I do not understand the meaning of the `(+)=` and the last `(+)`.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: 1. Your textbook is well out of date for supplying outdated syntax. Ask for a refund. 2. The solution posed for eliminating duplicates makes absolutely no sense. Another reason to ask for a refund.

Comment: I totally agree... if this is a full outer join, then it does not eliminate duplicates!

Comment: Would the accepted solution to this question be the solution to removing duplicate values?

Comment: It's a SELECT so it does't remove anything. It there were duplicates in table a or b (based on key) then it would generate more duplicates. Nothing in this question identifies or removes duplicates. Obviously @GordonLinoff is correctly answering the original question about the `(+)` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you should stop using old-style joins with the condition in the `where` clause and *always* use explicit `join` syntax.

For your particular query, the equivalent is `full outer join`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table_a FULL OUTER JOIN
     table_b
     ON table_a.key = table_b.key;
```

Comment: So a (+)= b is like a left join b and a = b (+) is like a right join b, which in total is a full outer join b?

Comment: @jasonC . . . To be honest, I can never remember off hand which is the left outer join and which is the right outer join.  (It is easy to find which is which on the web).  Even when I used the syntax (once upon a time), I found it confusing.