# Excluding joined records on column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

For example, if I have Balls and Boxes, balls can be in many boxes, and boxes can be locked, how can I select the balls that are not in a locked box?

```
balls
  id  name
  ==  ====
  1   in neither
  2   in unlocked
  3   in locked
  4   in both

boxes
  id  locked
  ==  ======
  1   0
  2   1

boxings
  ball_id box_id
  ======= ======
  2       1
  3       2
  4       1
  4       2
```

I've come up with this using left joins, but it's returning the "in both" ball
which I want to exclude.

```
SELECT balls.* 
FROM balls 
LEFT OUTER JOIN boxings ON boxings.ball_id = balls.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN boxes ON boxes.id = boxings.box_id 
WHERE (boxings.box_id IS NULL or boxes.locked = 0)
  AND boxes.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM boxes WHERE locked = 1
    )
```

Desired results:

```
id  name
==  ====
1   in neither
2   in unlocked
```

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c26ab/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean:  choose balls that are never in a locked box.

If so, a `not exists` query comes to mind:

```
select b.*
from balls b
where not exists (select 1
                  from boxings bxb join
                       boxes bo
                       on bxb.box_id = bo.id
                  where bxb.ball_id = b.id and bo.locked = 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforwad way to do this is probably with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select id, name 
from balls 
where not exists (
  select NULL 
  from boxings 
  inner join boxes on boxes.id = boxings.box_id 
  where boxes.locked = 1
  and boxings.ball_id = balls.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it interesting that both answers already posted both take the same slightly odd approach of putting some of the join criteria in the `WHERE` clause:

```
inner join boxes on boxes.id = boxings.box_id
where boxes.locked = 1
```

What is most odd is that I'm sure [the same people advise elsewhere to not put join conditions in `WHERE` clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928719/what-does-this-sql-statement-where-table-a-key-table-b-key-means/30928733#30928733).

Anyway, here's a different variation on the anti-join approach:

```
SELECT *
  FROM balls
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT ball_id
                     FROM boxings
                          NATURAL JOIN 
                          ( SELECT id AS box_id FROM boxes WHERE locked = 1 )
                          NATURAL JOIN 
                          ( SELECT id AS ball_id FROM boxings ) );
```